# Compiling Makefile on Mac vs Linux

Tags: makefile, compilation

I compiled my makefile for my C++ program on my Mac and it compiled just fine. I tried doing the same thing on my Linux machine with the exact same files and got:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++abi
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [allocate-asan] Error 1
```

I do not know how I can go about compiling this on my linux machine with this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe install `libc++` development version. ( libc++-dev ).

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for your comment. I just checked and I've got libc++ installed on my linux machine...Any other ideas?

Comment: `libc++`  is the default standard library on OS X https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html . Linux: `libstdc++`. (libc++ is used with CLANG.)

Comment: @KnudLarsen Are you suggesting I see if libstdc++ is installed and if not, install it?

Comment: If you have `/usr/bin/g++` you already have "libstdc++ - devel", i.e. `libstdc++.so and C++ headers. ... If you want help from c++ coders, you should edit your question to include some code showing the libc++ inclusion.

Comment: On my system `libc++abi.a` and `libc++abi.so` (I don't know if you're linking static or dynamic version above) would be both in llvm package. Your mileage might vary between distros.